# What do I put in htaccess to create a 410 error page when a URL parameter is present?

Tags: google, htaccess, google-index, 410-gone

I tried to create a 410 error page but realized that I actually created a 302 redirect to a `410.php` page. Instead I want to use a 410 error to block out an infinite number of dynamically created pages that are being indexed by Google. I have about 30k internal links that are indexed on Google thanks to a faulty internal search engine:

- `http://www.example.com/?searchkey=1_q`
- `http://www.example.com/?searchkey=2ak`    - (etc... goes on for 30k times)

What should I write in `htaccess` to block anything with this "searchkey" parameter such that a 410 error page is served? (I'm not a programmer, so I would appreciate a simplified response.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this using the following rewrite rule in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} searchkey
RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
```

- `.*` means that it will do this for any URL on your site (as long as the condition of having "searchkey" in the query string is met)
- `-` means to leave the URL alone and not change it
- `G` means "Gone" -- send the 410 status
- `L` means "Last" -- so that no other rewrite rules are executed

Since you have a custom 410 gone page, you could also use the following `.htaccess` directive to show it instead of the default 410 gone error page:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution & helping me rephrase my question, worked great!